# authentication - connect to datalab from compute engine

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I would like to connect to bigQuery from datalab and execute update commands.
I run the following code for the API & authentication:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Get everything we possibly can from the service account JSON file
#set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
cred = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('OrielResearch-da46e752c7ff.json')
# Instantiates a client
client = bigquery.Client(project='speedy-emissary-167213',credentials=cred)
# The name of the dataset
dataset_name = 'pgp_orielresearch'
# The name of the table
table_name = 'update_queries'
# Perform a synchronous query.
QUERY = (
    'SELECT * FROM [speedy-emissary-167213:pgp_orielresearch.update_queries]')
query = client.run_sync_query(QUERY)
dataset = client.dataset(dataset_name)
tables, token = dataset.list_tables()
```

and get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'authorize'

any idea?

the full stack is:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-616f54fa35ba> in <module>()
     19 query = client.run_sync_query(QUERY)
     20 dataset = client.dataset(dataset_name)
---> 21 t = dataset.list_tables()
     22 #query.timeout_ms = TIMEOUT_MS
     23 #query.run()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/dataset.py in list_tables(self, max_results, page_token)
    568         connection = self._client.connection
    569         resp = connection.api_request(method='GET', path=path,
--> 570                                       query_params=params)
    571         tables = [Table.from_api_repr(resource, self)
    572                   for resource in resp.get('tables', ())]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/connection.pyc in api_request(self, method, path, query_params, data, content_type, api_base_url, api_version, expect_json, _target_object)
    344         response, content = self._make_request(
    345             method=method, url=url, data=data, content_type=content_type,
--> 346             target_object=_target_object)
    347 
    348         if not 200 <= response.status < 300:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/connection.pyc in _make_request(self, method, url, data, content_type, headers, target_object)
    242         headers['User-Agent'] = self.USER_AGENT
    243 
--> 244         return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
    245 
    246     def _do_request(self, method, url, headers, data,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/connection.pyc in _do_request(self, method, url, headers, data, target_object)
    270         :returns: The HTTP response object and the content of the response.
    271         """
--> 272         return self.http.request(uri=url, method=method, headers=headers,
    273                                  body=data)
    274 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/connection.pyc in http(self)
    101             self._http = httplib2.Http()
    102             if self._credentials:
--> 103                 self._http = self._credentials.authorize(self._http)
    104         return self._http
    105 

AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'authorize'
```

Comment: I connect to the datalab from google cloud engine (not from local machine)

Answer (score 1):

Trying setting the credentials like so:

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'OrielResearch-da46e752c7ff.json'
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

client = Client()
```